# C++, finding parent and calling it's method?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, overriding

I'd like to say that I have looked for a solution to this issue here but just could not find exactly what I was looking for. There may be a simple solution to my issue.

So take this example:

```
class Component
{
public:
    virtual ~Component() {} // Make Polymorphic;

    void Update() {};
};
class UserMadeComponent : public Component
{
public:

    void Update() {};
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Component*> _components;

    UserMadeComponent* UsersComponent = new UserMadeComponent;

    _components.push_back(UsersComponent);

    while (true)
    {
        for (auto _comp = _components.begin(); _comp != _components.end(); _comp++)
        {
            (*_comp)->Update();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the programmer, using this framework, can create any type of component they want. And they will add this to the component vector. I want to be able to get the type of component and call its Update method. Here is a little diagram of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: Link to image]

So the goal is to call the "parents" update method. However, the user can create any type of component they'd like. I can't assume the type of any component inside this array. I hope this makes sense

//EDIT//

Thanks for people helping me to understand the virtual method calling. But how would I know what that class actually is. For example, the user has created a component called "Transform". I only want to allow one Transform instance in the component array. But obviously if I only know its a component pointer, I can't check for this occurrence.

It's hard to explain so here is another image:

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2F9v.png)

Comment: How do virtual functions not work for you here?  also, why the underscore prefix? Please don't do that.

Comment: Aren't you already calling the parent's update "method"?

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it backwards. Instead, create a virtual method called `do_update` that your derived classes override. The parent class's `update` method should call the virtual `do_update` method, which will dispatch properly.

This is how the Standard Library does it...

Comment: "This is how the Standard Library does it." - where?

Comment: He's not doing it backwards at all. This is literally exactly what subclassing is for.

Comment: @Josh Given the lack of clarity in the question, it is as likely that this is the right approach as it is yours.

Comment: He gives an explanation of the intended interface, and example code for his implementation AND how to use it with his main. How is it unclear?

Comment: @Josh Like this: "So the goal is to call the "parents" update method"

Comment: If he *really* wants to call the parents update method, Component::update().

Comment: @Josh If you had bothered to look at the picture OP provided, you'll see what he really wants, which is a very common dispatch pattern.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Look at any stream class in the Standard Library.

Comment: I have managed to sort the call now, thanks for the input. Could anyone provide anything for the bottom bit however, it's the same problem just in a different context

Comment: @Dúthomhas  Those are big classes - where exact;ly should I look?

Comment: @Dúthomhas you mean the big picture where he has a blue line to the child update and a big red arrow to the parent update. Meaning literally classic polymorphism with virtual function? He added this bit with the Transofrm after the fact, which again something you can handle with classic polymorphism with a dynamic_cast and a nullptr check.

Comment: @Josh It appears he keeps changing his image.

Answer (score 2):

Use a virtual method.

Parent:

```
virtual void Update();
```

If you want the Component class to be "pure virtual," meaning you have to subclass it and it just represents an abstraction/interface, you can do:

```
virtual void Update() = 0;
```

This will give you an error if you try to instantiate a Component object, you create subclass objects only which implement all the pure virtual methods.

Edit:

The below code checks if x is a Transform. However, doing this means that you probably have a design flaw. Why not make a semantically aware container that stops a user from adding two transforms instead?

```
dynamic_cast<Transform*>(x) == nullptr
```

Comment: I have this now, it's working fine. But how do I get the type of that class like what it was created as. I have extended my post

Comment: Hi @ReeceWard, generally you should ask one question at a time. If you have another question, you should mark a correct answer and open another question.